# Passing dates or date ranges into a view as arguments

Tags: 7, views, datetime

Drupal 7, [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) modules installed.

I have a view on a content type with a date field (timestamp, but I can change it if necessary)

When I use it in filter criteria, I have no problem to use criteria like Mydate greater than, less than, between, not between etc.
But if I try to do the same thing using contextual filters I have only the "equal" criteria. I need to do this, so i can call the view from code passing arguments to it.

I found some pages about Drupal 6 where is written that i can pass parameter to the filter in format: `2008-11-12--2010-11-12`, but when i try to make it and hit 'update preview', i obtain: `(field_data_field_test_date.field_test_date_value = '2008-01-01--2010-12-31')` in the query.

I need to:

- use criteria greater than, less than, between
- pass date range to the view

Does anybody have some suggestion on how I can do it?

Comment: @OwenBlacker We *don't* cross-post on sites in the SE network, that's considered *noise*.  This is being migrated though, and you should recommend that in the future

Comment: @casperOne That makes complete sense. I'll bear that in mind in future. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL and check the answer given by @Dmitriy

[How to implement less than / greater than in views contextual filters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35128/how-to-implement-less-than-greater-than-in-views-contextual-filters)

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Views Contextual Range Filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter)

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for Views that adds
>   the option to contextually filter not just by a single value, but also
>   by range.
>
> Numeric, alphabetical and list ranges are all supported. Node ids,
>   user ids and even taxonomy term ids are all special cases of numbers
>   so will work also. Range-filtering on dates is also supported. For
>   this you may use either the absolute date format as dictated by Views,
>   YYYYMMDD, or the relative format, which supports natural language
>   phrases like six months ago, today noon and even first Tuesday of
>   November