# How to implement less than / greater than in views contextual filters

Tags: 7, views

I want to filter my view like

`field_opening_hour_start_time > <?php date("g"); ?>`

How can I make this happen? The filter criteria does not let me to use PHP and the contextual filter does not let me to use less than (or greater than), but only equal (=) comparison. Is there a way around this? Or a way to use PHP in filter criteria box?

edit. I am using Office hours module

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the regular filter (granularity of hour) and selecting the 'relative date' instead of the hard-coded date?  You could use 'now' to do a greater than or or equal to the current time, which is the same as

Screenshot attached:

[image]

Comment: And in this case the problem is that the time value is seen as an integer and I don't know how I could modify it to look like time - that would probably be the perfect scenario.

Comment: Didn't think about this but solved my issue

Answer (score 5):

You could use `hook_views_query_alter()` for this. Look example. Use `print_r()` or devel functions such as `dpm()` to view how your field is called.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter()
 */
function occ_search_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'restaurants') {
    if (isset($query->where[0])) {
      if (trim($query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['field']) == 'field_data_field_max_group_size.field_max_group_size_value = :field_data_field_max_group_size_field_max_group_size_value') {
        // Use '>=' condition instead of '='
        $query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['field'] = 'field_data_field_max_group_size.field_max_group_size_value >= :field_data_field_max_group_size_field_max_group_size_value';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use this sandbox project [views arguments in filter](http://drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472). It permit to use arguments in filter criteria and then all the operators of the filter criteria with the arguments.