# Node relations (one content type)

Tags: nodes, views

Question: I have a content type "VIDEOS" and have added 20 videos - 1 through 20. I want to achieve a functionality like if you are watching video x, the next 3 videos are showing in the sidebar, example -> when you are watching video 2 in a block in the sidebar videos 3, 4, 5 are showing up. When you watch video 7 - in the sidebar videos 8, 9 10 are showing up and so on.
Any ideas? I know it will be done somehow with Views but cannot figure it out.

BR, Ivan Ivanov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do that with a little code in a custom module...

For the purposes of this example my module is called misc, but replace everywhere is says misc with the name of your your module.

First create a block:

```
function misc_block_info() {
    $blocks['next_four'] = array(
        'info' => t('Show the next 4'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );
    return $blocks;
}
```

And then define where it's content comes from:

```
function misc_block_view($delta = '') {
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'next_four':
            $block['subject'] = '';
            $block['content'] = next_four();
            break;

    }
    return $block;
}
```

And then define the content of the block:

```
function next_four() {
    $output = '';
    if(arg(0)=='node') {
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
        $query = db_select('node', 'n')
            ->fields('n', array('nid'))
            ->condition('n.type', $node->type)
            ->condition('n.status', 1)
            ->condition('n.nid', $node->nid, '>')
            ->range(0, 4)
            ->orderBy('n.nid', 'ASC');
        $nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
        $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

        $output .= '<ul>';
        foreach($nodes as $node) {
            $output .= '<li><a href="'.drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid).'">'.$node->title.'</a></li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>'; 
    }
    return $output;
}
```

What this code does is:

1. Take the nid of the current node
2. Does a query to get more nodes of the same type with an nid height than the current page.
3. Loads each node and outputs the node title, with a link to the node.

This will work for any content type. If your HTML is going to be any more complex than this then I would suggest using the hook_theme function to create a template file for your block.

Comment: Hoped to do it via Views as this is a bit advanced for me. I will try it though and will let you know the result. Much appreciated. Cheers :)

Comment: I've put together all of that code into a custom module for you so you can just install it and it'll work out the box: http://felixeve.co.uk/next_x_items.zip - take a look at the code too - should be some good example if you want to learn more about module development in the future...

Comment: U rock man ;) will try it tomorrow morning and will share...

Comment: to do it in views you will need a "great than" contextual filter: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35128/how-to-implement-less-than-greater-than-in-views-contextual-filters